# Setting captions on Galleria photo gallery

Tags: jquery, photo-gallery, galleria

I am using Galleria and I would like to use the classic theme and have captions. Is that possible? If so how do I set it up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, the [classic demo](http://galleria.io/themes/classic/) has captions (clicking on the top left *i* displays the caption), you only have to set the `alt` and optionally the `title` element of the `img` tag and you are done.

If you don't see it ensure you set [showInfo](http://galleria.io/docs/options/showInfo/) option to `true` and if you want to display it all the time, search in the classic theme's js file this line:

```
// set this to false if you want to show the caption all the time:
_toggleInfo: true
```

and set `_toggleInfo` to `false`

Comment: it is _toggleInfo not _toggle_info

Comment: It was _toggle_info back then... https://github.com/aino/galleria/blob/033577d8719e8382ad5d0227d7b80036426a2d9b/src/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js thanks for noticing it for newcomers :-D

Answer (score 3):

Found at [Galleria's quick start page](http://galleria.io/docs/getting_started/quick_start/) (works with the classic theme):

```
<div id="galleria">
    <img src="/img/pic1.jpg" data-title="My title" data-description="My description">
    <img src="/img/pic2.jpg" data-title="Another title" data-description="My HTML description">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Found out with Firebug that the div's are there but that the standard theme's CSS these blocks doesn't display.

So basicly remove line 76 from galleria.classic.css:
    display: none;

After this it still needs some tweaking to make it look good, but at least you know where the problem comes from.

Comment: This is hacky, @maid450's solution requires no extra CSS to work.